# Why are buttons loosing their 3d style when I change my Twitter.Bootstrap version from 2.3 to 3.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on integrating Twitter.Bootstrap into a new site I'm creating and my buttons looked flat and not like the examples. After playing around with it for a bit I was able to get the 3d looking buttons by changing the style sheet and  javascript references to use an older version.

Here's is the working code for 2.3.1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <button class="btn">hello</button>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Displays like shown below

[image]

Here's the same code with only the version number updated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <button class="btn">hello</button>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which displays with a flat style as shown below. Looking at it here I am realizing that there are some other style issues too. Like the margins look wrong and the font looks off.

[image]

Comment: Buttons in Twitter Bootstrap have a different style altogether, but you must add `btn-default` for the default style. See the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll find an asset called `bootstrap-theme{.min}.css`, which contains optically improved styles:

```
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Check out the new template `theme` on [getbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/).